# Angular Material: layout-fill not filling parent <div>

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, flexbox, material-design

```
<!-- Container Div -->
<div layout-fill>
    <!-- Image Div -->
    <div layout="column" layout-align="center center" class="coverImage" layout-fill>
        <md-content class="md-padding">
            Sample Text Here
        </md-content>
        <md-button class="md-raised md-primary">Sign Up</md-button>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have the above section of HTML, and I'm trying to use Angular Material's flexbox support to create a page that has a background image that is the full page.  Overlayed on this image is some text and a button that is in the center of the image.

If I inspect the outermost div in chrome it's size is (as expected) the full screen.  The image div for some reason does not do this.  It only takes up enough space to contain the text and button.  Any insights on why this is happening would be appreciated.  I know that this can be done in several different ways using various css tricks but I would like to learn what im missing about how flex works.

**Update**
Link to [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1tap45pp/)

Comment: make a fiddle for this.

Comment: I think I set this up correctly.... [link](http://jsfiddle.net/1tap45pp/)

Comment: Here is yr new fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1tap45pp/9

Comment: If you like the answer that currently has 6 upvotes. You might want to accept it. By doing so you're awarding his effort. Here's how and why: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 10):

I guess the fundamental issue comes from using both `layout-align` and `layout-fill` in the same parent container.

## Solutions

In short, there are 2 ways to overcome this:

1. Add a custom css rule on parent container with `align-items: stretch;`
2. Use only `layout-fill` (no `layout-align` on the parent container)

---

## Reasons

Whenever using `layout-*` directive, angular-material would add a class to the element, and apply flex layout related styles there. For example:

```
<div class="parent" layout="row" layout-align="space-between center" layout-fill> 
  <div class="child child-1" flex>
  <div class="child child-2" flex="none">
</div>
```

Will be compiled to :

```
<div class="parent layout-fill layout-align-space-between-center layout-row" layout="row" layout-align="space-between center" layout-fill> 
  <div class="child child-1 flex" flex>
  <div class="child child-2 flex-none" flex="none">
</div>
```

And the resulting css would be:

```
.layout {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
}

.layout-row {
    flex-direction: row;
}

.layout-align-space-between-center {
    align-items: center;
    align-content: center;
    max-width: 100%;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.layout-fill {
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

As you can see here, `layout-fill` does not change anything in flex related-rules at all.

What we expect for a stretched flex item should leverage on `align-items: stretch` as mentioned in this [A Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) by CSS-tricks. But this simply is not the case for angular material implementation. And it make sense because `align-item` rule is already being used in `layout-align-*` as a way to position the item.

## Examples

Check this [codepen example](http://codepen.io/kavare/pen/wWRjVd?editors=1100) to see how it works.

Comment: Thanks @kavare....There is no explanation available on the angular material web site as to what does layout-fill , layout-wrap does...or how does it translate to code..So this is helpful

Answer (score 0):

```
<div layout-fill>
<img src="" class="bg" alt="image you want in background"></img>
<div layout="column" layout-align="center center">
    <md-content class="md-padding">
        Sample Text Here
    </md-content>
    <md-button class="md-raised md-primary">Sign Up</md-button>
</div>
</div>
```

and add this to yr CSS

```
  img.bg {
  /* Set rules to fill background */
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 1024px;

  /* Set up proportionate scaling */
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;

  /* Set up positioning */
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Like I said, I know there are many alternate ways to write this that would work, if I just wanted everything to render correctly.  My main concern I why layout-fill on the image div is not filling the parent div.  In other words I wish to understand why it is not working as is, not just a solution to the problem.

Comment: I was out, sorry for late reply. In yr case, you need to add "position:absolute" in yr layout-fill class inside css.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late 
You need to add "layout"-attribute to the div where your layout-fill is.